# controlling focus on press of next in android

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext

i have following .xml layout file

[image]

By default in android ,after entering text in one `edittext` and clicking next from android keypad, focus shifts to the next `edittext` .How ever what if i want to control the focus, i.e on click of `next` from android keypad i want some other editext to attain focus rather the consecutive one.Something like,i may be requiring the following sequence:

[image]

How can i achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try out with `android:nextFocusDown` in your xml as below:

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Text 1"
        android:singleLine="true"
         android:nextFocusDown="@+id/Text4" >
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Text 2"
        android:singleLine="true"
         android:nextFocusDown="@+id/editText5" >
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" 
        android:singleLine="true">
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Text4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Text 3"
        android:singleLine="true"
         android:nextFocusDown="@+id/editText2" >
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:hint="Text 4" >
    </EditText>
```

Comment: Ok I will give it a try and will let you know

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
editText1.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT) {
        editText3.requestFocus();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
});
```

**UPDATE**
You can use

> android:nextFocusDown

from xml too.

Comment: @GrIsHu kind of solution,but I am looking for something more systematic or easy(may be xml modifications)....looking for further reponses

Comment: @Butterflow you could try android:nextFocus if you need xml based solution